# Powerbi How to countdays and seperate them in a matris

Tags: powerbi

Hi i have a Questian how i can take this values in the picture.

I have one where a customer have a from and to date.

and i have a price for every customer.

And there is a datetable if there is needed

The blue is the result i would like to get.

[image]

messurement
_Days = DateDiff(From,To,Day)

but i understand this is not so easy. I have to generate some temp table
with CountOfDays and then Year and month i think. But i dont know how